# Mypy typing for kwargs in case of inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy

I have found couples of answers about how to handle `kwargs` with MyPy. But actually my problem is that mypy does not properly catch this:

```
from typing import Union


class Parent:
    def __init__(self, a: int, b: str) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, c: float, **kwargs: Union[int, str]) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c


child = Child(a="a", b=2, c=2.3)

# tmp.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "Parent" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, Union[int, str]]"; expected "int"
# tmp.py:12: error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "Parent" has incompatible type "**Dict[str, Union[int, str]]"; expected "str"
# Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I don't know how to handle this case. I don't want to update the `Child.__init__` because it is a less maintainable pattern.

Comment: Can you clarify what you think "this" is? Did you expect MyPy to warn at the ``child = ...`` line as well?

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. Mypy does *not* warn at the line ``child = ...``, and *neither* ``int`` nor ``str`` (nor ``Union[int, str]``!) would be correct for ``kwargs``. ``**kwargs`` inherently implies that *any* valid type may appear as *any* parameter which is not compatible with ``Parent.__init__`` requiring *specific* types.

Comment: agreed, I mis red the error line. It could be nice if kwargs typing could be a TypedDict

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue which has been unresolved for a while (https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1969).

Comment: How is this related? The issue seems to be about mypy erroneously assuming ``**`` could unpack to ``*`` parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work, but is it only a workaround?

```
from typing import overload

class Parent:

    def __init__(self, a: int, b: str) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Child(Parent):

    @overload
    def __init__(self, c: float) -> None: ...

    @overload
    def __init__(self, c: float, * , a: int=..., b: str=...) -> None: ...

    def __init__(self, c: float, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.c = c


child = Child(2.3)
child = Child(2.3, a=3)
child = Child(2.3, b='5')
child = Child(2.3, a=3, b='5')
child = Child(a=3, b='5', c=2.3)
child = Child(a=3, b='5')  # mypy error ok
child = Child(a='3', b='5', c=2.3)  # mypy error ok
child = Child(a=3, b=5, c=2.3)  # mypy error ok
child = Child(a=3, b='5', c='2.3')  # mypy error ok
```

Comment: at least learnt two things with this proposal: positional `*` and `@overload`!

Comment: mypy is more complex than python :-)

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10079